# Sphinx search: Connection to 127.0.0.1 on 9312 failed. Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I try to use Sphinx in my Rails app in production mode but without any success.
Every time, when I tried run my search action I get an error:

> Connection to 127.0.0.1 on 9312 failed. Connection refused -
>   connect(2)

I also tried to change port from 9312 to 9845, but it's not changed(

Does anybody have ideas how resolve this issue?

Comment: Did u install sphinx search deamon?  did u launch it? rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=production if it is installed then kill searchd process and start it wih rake command

Comment: already tried, didn't work. As I can figure out, origin of problem in config file, but I can't find its location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, problem was with searchd deamon. I just pkill old process and restart with

> RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:restart